# Adding guestbook to my wordpress site

Tags: custom-post-types, user-access, comment-form

I´m trying to add something like a guestbook, where the user can write about our services, something like comments with few more content like country, facebook page... should i do this with a single page extending the default comments using with wordpress or i have to add a new content type? How can i give the user permission tu publish without register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way by far would be as you suggested to use a page coupled with comments. Restyle it so that it looks more like a guestbook.

I'm sure there are plugins out there that do this but I don't see the point as you'll need to restyle them anyway and it just slows down your site.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a custom page template that pulls output from a custom post type.  You could have a form at the bottom of this page which would allow users to submit their own content.

The page template and post type are easy, just a file and `register_post_type()`, the form is a bit more complicated. You can use `wp_insert_post()` to do most of it, but depending on what else you want to do with it, you may need `update_post_meta()` as well to handle any data not covered by the default function.

Comment: using post types would be ideal, but what I did was extend the functionality of the comments using the `comment_form_default_fields` filter using a personalized page template